# 'Crop to selection' option is greyed out in GIMP 2.10

Tags: gimp

The 'Crop to selection' option in the 'Image' menu of GIMP 2.10 is greyed out. How to solve it? The operating system is Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

In GIMP 2.10 make sure that the mode is set to Replace the current selection, or the first box to the right of "Mode:" shown here below "Tool Options" then "Rectangle Select":

[image]

Now your "Crop to Selection" should work fine:

[image]

Comment: So it works, thank you.